# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such interface supported

Tags: c#, .net, process, windows-server-2008

Having an issue with a program that is launched by a windows service.

The process flow is

- exe launches
- renames itself to *.bak
- downloads the latest version of itself
- calls `Restart()`
- does a bunch of file and SQL operations (updating our main software suite)
- then calls `Restart()`
- Process flow starts again. IF there were no software updates for the main suite it does not restart

**this all works perfect except for one customer site**

On one site, the first `Restart()` works, but the second one always throws an exception.

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such interface supported
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo  startInfo)
>     at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>    at UpdateCompanionService.Program.Restart()

It is a WS2008 standard server.

```
public static void Restart()
{
  try
  {
      var procPath = Path.Combine(Config.UpdateCompanionDirectory, "UpdateCompanionService.exe");
      Logger.Debug("Starting procecss {0}", procPath);

      var proc = new Process
      {
          StartInfo = {FileName = procPath, WorkingDirectory = Config.UpdateCompanionDirectory, Arguments = "/noupdate", UseShellExecute = true}
      };

      proc.Start();
      Environment.Exit(-1);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Logger.Fatal("Error restarting update companion", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant How did you come to this conclusion that his machine is 'quite broken'?

Comment: The stack trace tells the tale.

Answer (score 7):

Try using

```
    UseShellExecute = false
```

Its been known to fix this problem

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set `UseShellExecute = false` in your code.

I remember some own problems long ago, where I even recompiled the original .NET framework code to find out that setting this flags uses a completely different method of starting.

For me it seems you do not need `UseShellExecute = true` in your case.

If this does not work, you should check security context / GPO settings, e.g.
"Is this service running as SYSTEM or (domain) user ?"

Also be sure that your new EXE with all additional components is "ready" at the time where you try to restart it (maybe you use a background thread which did not complete).

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue with an executable which is called by a Web Application running on IIS. In my case the solution was to restart the Application Pool for to current Web Application.